# How to differentiate the summary from the description in TortoiseGit commits?

Tags: git, git-commit, tortoisegit

On Github, for example, we can put a Summary message in the commits, but we can also put a Description message, so when a colaborator wants to see a description of the commit, he can know more details of it:

[image: Commiting messages on GitHub]

How can we do it when commiting a message in TortoiseGit, as he only gives you 1 input to write your message?

Comment: That's just a UI abstraction, within Git itself it's just one message. The convention is that the first line of the message is the "title", the rest (usually separated by one blank line) is the "description".

Comment: @jonrsharpe isn't the title also restricted in character length?

Comment: @evolutionxbox again, that's a convention that GitHub has adopted into the UI. If you make commits from another client, not necessarily; it will be truncated on GitHub pages, but the first line can be as long as you like.

Comment: @jonrsharpe VIM only highlights the first 50 characters... maybe that's also convention.

Comment: @evolutionxbox there is no restriction, just a recommendation of [50 characters or less for the first line of the commit message](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#_discussion).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's just an additional input field on GitHub. Both lines are concatenated with an empty line.

So, in TortoiseGit just use an empty line as separator (that's the official git convention: use the first line as subject and the following lines as body/description, cf. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#_discussion and https://chris.beams.io/posts/git-commit/).

Comment: It's ironic that the first three words on the git pages are "Though not required" however GitHub seem to have decided to take a hardline approach at enforcing this as a standard, though it is not.

Answer (score 1):

You can write the Summary and Description in the same input box in TortoiseGit, separated by a blank line.